# mathtype equation are not converting in editable format

Tags: equations

I am trying to convert the document. It is converting but the 'mathtype' equations are not coming in editable format; they are coming in PNG format. could you please tell how to convert the equation for editable?

```
T1 = Q(0) =
1/2
.(lamda_1)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. For anyone to answer this we need more information. What kind of document are you converting, and how are you doing the conversion (i.e., with what program)?

Comment: If the equations really are in .png format, i.e., separate graphic files, you're probably out of luck. Files of .png type are raster fonts, and there's no automated way to transform th contents of those images files directly into LaTeX code.

Comment: How did you convert the document to LaTeX? Was it written in OpenOffice, Word, or something else?